# Django UpdateView for Profile model that also includes a User form

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Using Django 2.x, I have a Profile model, and I want to update some User fields in the Profile's UpdateView, for example, User.email

I can get the email field to display, and to show the current value, but I can't figure out how to get it to update.

Here's my setup:

**models.py:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other fields
```

**forms.py:**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('email')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=(...)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model=Profile
    form_class = ProfileForm
    user_form_class = UserForm


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        user = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).user

        context['user_form']= self.user_form_class(instance=user)
```

Everything up to here seems to work.  The user form works and the current email address appears in the form.  However, this is where I get stuck, I don't know how to save that email address.

Still within the ProfileUpdate, this is what I'm trying:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_form = self.user_form_class(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
          user_form.save()
          # code makes it this far when submitting form.

    return super(ProfileUpdate, self).post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Although the code is run, only the Profile model is updated, the User model doesn't get an updated email address.

Answer (score 0):

Give `django-shapeshifter` a try: https://github.com/kennethlove/django-shapeshifter

`pip install django-shapeshifter`

The example in the README does exactly what you are looking for. Full disclosure, I'm a contributor to the project.

Good luck!

Comment: woah cool, thanks!  Can your project be used with django-crispy-forms?

Comment: I think it should be able to, as I believe `django-crispy-forms` just wraps regular Django forms. Give it a try!